# Unwind segue to view controller containing SpriteKit's SKView is extremely slow

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I've just started playing around with SpriteKit, and this issue pretty much immediately cropped up. If I have a view controller whose view is an SKView, pushing another view controller on top of it (say, a pause menu or an end game menu) and then unwinding back to the view controller with the SKView takes a noticeable amount of time, in my experience on a 4S and a 5, about a second and a half.

You can test this using the default Hello World template. I set it as the root controller of a navigation view and stuck a button in the navigation bar to trigger a push segue to a new view controller. The second view controller contains a button which triggers an unwind segue. When the button gets pressed, it stays highlighted for about a second and a half, and then finally the segue happens, which is incredibly jarring to the user.

I've glanced through the SpriteKit documentation and didn't notice anything written about the proper use of segues, is this just a bug or is it considered bad practice to push new views on top of an SKView? Instead, should I be using SKNodes/SKScenes to present my pause and end game menus, thereby always keeping the SKView on screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9203) helpful. I was planning on using multiple UIViewControllers to navigate to different sections of my game like a menu screen, game over screen etc. but it was painfully slow. After refactoring my app to use a single UIViewController whose view is of type SKView, and creating a new scene for each screen I wanted, it started to work properly. At first I thought that this would be a pain because the controller would end up getting unmanageable, but found that most of logic was incapsulated in each SKScene and the controller was used to present new scenes only.

Also, you should note that adding UIKit controls to the SKView from an SKScene is acceptable. This is what I am doing to avoid having to reinvent the wheel every time I need a UIScrollView, UIButton or any other UIKit control. Of course you will have to remove the UIKit stuff you don't want to share between scenes when you transition.

Comment: This sounds like the best idea, since I posted this I realized that transitioning between different SKScenes seemed like the best idea. I didn't even think about adding subviews to the view, I just created my own button class as an SKLabelNode subclass, but it does seem to make more sense to do that rather than reinvent everything. Just a pain that I won't fully be able to use storyboards I guess, but not too hard to live with.

Comment: Great answer. Both paragraphs are quite relevant and concise.

Comment: Question though -- do you programmatically position most of your SKScene view (both UIKit and SK) elements?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure whether that's best practice or not, but I've always positioned everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that the SKView (or the scene) deallocates while the menu storyboard is presented? That would explain the delay when returning to the scene. Set a breakpoint in the corresponding dealloc messages of custom view/scene subclasses or use Instruments to check for the view and scene being among the live objects while the menu is presented.

Another possibility could be textures being removed from memory and then having to be reloaded. There could be an automatism in Sprite Kit, hard to say.

Try changing the way your storyboards are connected, for example have a "main menu" storyboard before the sprite kit view. It would be interesting to see if you get the same effect entering the view (repeatedly) as you do going back to it.

FWIW I only did a few tests with SK and storyboards but haven't noticed such a delay.

Comment: It can't be textures, I get this delay even when I don't create a scene and just present a blank SKView. If I go into my storyboard and switch it to a blank UIView, there's zero delay. Then when I switch it back to an SKView, the delay returns even without adding back in the scene setup code. Like I said, I've tested this on both a 4S and a 5 and get the same results. I should have mentioned that I don't see any issues in the simulator, if that's what you're testing it on. I also checked, it's not being deallocated, so that can't be it either. I'll have to try reversing the segue order later.

Comment: So, just reversed the view controller order like you suggested. I set up a storyboard with a UIViewController and created a segue to a controller containing an SKView. I then called performSegue:withIdentifier: in my first view controller's viewDidLoad so that the SKView was effectively the rootViewController. This worked perfectly, zero lag, even though it had to create a new instance of the SKView to push on top of the stack every time. I am confused.